# Android alarmManager broadcastreceiver restart once completed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an app with multiple alarms at the same time. Those alarms must restart once completed. My problem actually is how to retrieve the requestCode of my alarm once it is received, or at least passing some parameters with the alarm and retrieve them once alarm completed. Is there a way to do it?

**here is my BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int SECS = 1000;
    private static final int MINS = 60000;
    private static final int HOURS = 3600000;
    private static final int DAYS = 86400000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent){
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        //qui metto il codice
        //todo codice
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Allarme!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        wl.release();

    }

    public void setAlarm(Context ctx, int sec, int min, int hours, int days, int requestCode){
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, requestCode, i, 0);
        int tempoInMilli = 0;
        tempoInMilli += (SECS * sec);
        tempoInMilli += (MINS * min);
        tempoInMilli += (HOURS * hours);
        tempoInMilli += (DAYS * days);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), tempoInMilli, pi);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context, int requestCode)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

**And this is my service**

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();



    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        int sec = extras.getInt("secondi");
        int min = extras.getInt("minuti");
        int hour = extras.getInt("ore");
        int days = extras.getInt("giorni");
        int requestCode = extras.getInt("requestCode");

        alarm.setAlarm(this, sec, min, hour, days, requestCode);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, my alarms are all saved with an id and the request code (plus a description and some other infos) with SQLite in the local db. The only goal i'm missing(i think) is to retrieve the requestCode or an identifier from the alarm when it is completed.

It's the first time I work with alarms so i might be missing something, so any tip will be appreciated!

Comment: Attach extras to the `Intent` you're using to create the `PendingIntent` for the alarm.

Comment: @MikeM. the intent you mean is the same i retrieve in the onReceive?

Comment: Yep. So whatever extras you attach to the `Intent` used to create the `PendingIntent` can be retrieved in `onReceive()`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks a lot, you saved my day! if you post it as an answer i will approve it, i'm going to test :)

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind, I'll just vote it as a duplicate of another question I just found, and you should be able to mark it as helpful to close out your question. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Sure! i didn't see it, I probably searched really badly, sorry and thanks again :)